# In Red Dead Redemption: Undead Nightmare, Can I Brew Tonic?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

More specifically, if I have completed the survivalist challenges in the regular game, do the rewards carry over to the zombie expansion?

Answer (score 2):

No, the rewards do not carry over.